# When I add an arrow to my circuitikz, the document wont compile

Tags: circuitikz

I want to make the following diagram of the setup for my project, but when I try to add a powerflow arrow the document wont compile.

code is below

```
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0)
    % PV Block
    to [short] (0,2.5)    
    to [short] (2,2.5)
    to [short] (2,0)
    to [short] (0,0)
    (0,2.5) to [short] (1,1.5)
    to [short] (2,2.5)
    
    % Lines to DC Boost
    (2,0.75) to [short] (4,0.75)
    (2,1.75) to [short] (4,1.75)
    (3,1.75) to [C] (3,0.75)
    
    % Boost converter
    (4,0.25) to [short] (4,2.25)
    to [short] (6,2.25)
    to [short] (6,0.25)
    to [short] (4,0.25)
    to [short] (6,2.25)
    
    %Lines to DC/AC
    (6,0.75) to [short] (10,0.75)
    (6,1.75) to [short] (10,1.75)
    (7,1.75) to [C] (7,0.75)
    
    % DC/AC
    (10,0.25) to [short] (10,2.25)
    to [short] (12,2.25)
    to [short] (12,0.25)
    to [short] (10,0.25)
    to [short] (12,2.25)
    
    % Lines to DC/DC Bidrectional
    (7.5,0.75) to [short] (7.5,-0.75)
    (8.5,1.75) to [short] (8.5,1)
    (8.5,0.5) to [short] (8.5,-0.75)
    (8.5,1) to [crossing] (8.5,0.5)
    
    % Bidirectional DC/DC
    (7,-0.75) to [short] (9,-0.75)
    to [short] (9, -2.75)
    to [short] (7,-2.75)
    to [short] (7,-0.75)
    (9,-0.75) to [short] (7,-2.75)
    
    % Lines to BESS
    (7.5,-2.75) to [short] (7.5,-3.5)
    (8.5,-2.75) to [short] (8.5,-3.5)
    
    % BESS
    (7,-3.5) to [short] (9,-3.5)
    to [short] (9, -4.5)
    to [short] (7,-4.5)
    to [short] (7,-3.5)
    
    % Display names
    (1,0.5) node[align=center]{PV Array}
    (4.5,1.65) node[align=center]{DC}
    (5.5,0.85) node[align=center]{DC}
    (10.5,1.65) node[align=center]{DC}
    (11.5,0.85) node[align=center]{AC}
    (8.5,-2.25) node[align=center]{DC}
    (7.5,-1.25) node[align=center]{DC}
    (8,-4) node[align=center]{BESS}
    
    % Arrows
    %\draw[-latex] (4,3) -- (6,3);
    
    \end{circuitikz}
```

Many thanks for answering

Comment: It's missing ";" on the penultimate line
And \draw[->,>=latex]... On the last

Comment: I am sorry, but it still wont compile it, can you give me an example?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `latex` arrow is from the deprecated `arrows` package. Are you loading it? Or try with `-Latex`. See, if you had given a complete, compilable example, and the error you get, we wouldn't be guessing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite don't get why you are manually re-building the blocks of `circuitikz` (all of them are available), and do so using `to[short]`... you can just use `--` in this case, there is no difference.

Anyway, if you change the last lines of your code into:

```
[...]
  (8,-4) node[align=center]{BESS}; %<--- Add a semicolon here!
    
    % Arrows
    \draw[-latex] (4,3) -- (6,3);
[...]
```

it compiles and gives

[image]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0)
    % PV Block
    -- (0,2.5) -- (2,2.5) -- (2,0) -- (0,0) (0,2.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,2.5)
    % Lines to DC Boost
    (2,0.75) -- (4,0.75) (2,1.75) -- (4,1.75) (3,1.75) to [C] (3,0.75)
    % Boost converter
    (4,0.25) -- (4,2.25) -- (6,2.25) -- (6,0.25) -- (4,0.25) -- (6,2.25)
    %Lines to DC/AC
    (6,0.75) -- (10,0.75) (6,1.75) -- (10,1.75) (7,1.75) to [C] (7,0.75)
    % DC/AC
    (10,0.25) -- (10,2.25) -- (12,2.25) -- (12,0.25) -- (10,0.25) -- (12,2.25)
    % Lines to DC/DC Bidrectional
    (7.5,0.75) -- (7.5,-0.75) (8.5,1.75) -- (8.5,1) (8.5,0.5) 
    -- (8.5,-0.75) (8.5,1) to [crossing] (8.5,0.5)
    % Bidirectional DC/DC
    (7,-0.75) -- (9,-0.75) -- (9, -2.75) -- (7,-2.75) -- (7,-0.75)
    (9,-0.75) -- (7,-2.75)
    % Lines to BESS
    (7.5,-2.75) -- (7.5,-3.5) (8.5,-2.75) -- (8.5,-3.5)
    % BESS
    (7,-3.5) -- (9,-3.5) -- (9, -4.5) -- (7,-4.5) -- (7,-3.5)
    % Display names
    (1,0.5) node[align=center]{PV Array}
    (4.5,1.65) node[align=center]{DC}
    (5.5,0.85) node[align=center]{DC}
    (10.5,1.65) node[align=center]{DC}
    (11.5,0.85) node[align=center]{AC}
    (8.5,-2.25) node[align=center]{DC}
    (7.5,-1.25) node[align=center]{DC}
    (8,-4) node[align=center]{BESS};
    % Arrows
    \draw[-latex] (4,3) -- (6,3);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer worked thanks! I am new to circuitikz and found the building of circuits confusing, so made sense for me to build the blocks manually. I dont quite understand what you mean with that they are already there?
And if it is not too much trouble how can i make the arrow thicker both its line and arrow head?

Comment: There are blocks for converters, PV cells, etc., that are already done; look at the manual (although most of them have just the single-wire anchors, at least until the next release). Maybe you should look at the Ti*k*Z manual tutorials: `\draw[thick, -latex] ...` will work (and `ultra thick`...)

Comment: Okay I will have a look!
I actually figured how to increase the thickness 10 min after with same command so thanks!